# How to make chrome extension in python?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I've explored the forums but all solutions are old and some packages are deprecated.

I want to create chrome extension and use python packages like scipy, regex and **scraping** libraries.

I'm a python developer and don't know javascript.

is there any way that I can create chrome extension entirely or most using in python?

Comment: The only way is to use a compiler into JS or a library that does it on-the-fly. If you tried those packages and they don't work then there is no other way.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

if you don't wanna use that way, u need to make chrome as ur default browser and simply use 
import webbrowser,

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/')

Answer (score 6):

You can make a standard Google Chrome extension with Python (server-less) https://pythonspot.com/en/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/

The idea is to compile Python to Javascript (technically a JS pre-compiler) using Rapydscript. Then include the generated script in the Chrome extension. The site above has a zip file with all the stuff inside.

I recommend using Rapydscript instead of Pyjamas. A Python script compiled with Rapydscript works like any other Chrome plugin.

Pyjamas scripts does not work well with Google Chrome (needs a special parameter when Chrome starts or server).